# Show navigation loader spinner with delay in angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx-store

I'm new to angular 2+ and RxJS, trying to get used to RxJS.

I show load spinner on route transitions, but only if it takes more then certain amount time, lats say 160ms
I have a load spinner as a separate component, with subscription to ngrx store, so I show/hide load spinner based on value in the sore (showSpinner)

In my app root component, I subscribe to router change events, and dispatch actions (SHOW_SPINNER/HIDE_SPINNER)
So the question is, Is there a simpler way to achieve it?

Here are parts of my code

```
....

export const navigationStreamForSpinnerStatuses = {
  NAVIGATION_STARTED: 'NAVIGATION_STARTED',
  NAVIGATION_IN_PROGRESS: 'NAVIGATION_IN_PROGRESS',
  NAVIGATION_ENDED: 'NAVIGATION_ENDED'
};
```

....

```
private navigationStartStream;
private navigationStartStreamWithDelay;
private navigationFinishStream;

constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>, private router: Router) {
  this.navigationStartStream = router.events
    .filter(event => {
      return event instanceof NavigationStart;
    })
    .map(() => navigationStreamForSpinnerStatuses.NAVIGATION_STARTED);

  this.navigationStartStreamWithDelay = this.navigationStartStream
    .delay(160)
    .map(() => navigationStreamForSpinnerStatuses.NAVIGATION_IN_PROGRESS);

  this.navigationFinishStream = router.events
    .filter(event => {
      return event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError;
    })
    .map(() => navigationStreamForSpinnerStatuses.NAVIGATION_ENDED);

  this.navigationStartStream
    .merge(this.navigationFinishStream)
    .merge(this.navigationStartStreamWithDelay)
    .pairwise()
    .subscribe([previousStatus, currentStatus] => {
      if (previousStatus !== navigationStreamForSpinnerStatuses.NAVIGATION_ENDED && currentStatus === navigationStreamForSpinnerStatuses.NAVIGATION_IN_PROGRESS) {
        this.store.dispatch({ type: StateLoaderSpinnerActionsTypes.SHOW_SPINNER });
      } else if (previousStatus === navigationStreamForSpinnerStatuses.NAVIGATION_IN_PROGRESS && currentStatus === navigationStreamForSpinnerStatuses.NAVIGATION_ENDED) {
        this.store.dispatch({ type: StateLoaderSpinnerActionsTypes.HIDE_SPINNER });
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize the `takeUntil` operator to cancel your spinner timer if it returns before the time. Additionally, create a hot observable using `timer` to trigger an action after a certain time has passed.

> `takeUntil` Returns the values from the source observable sequence until the other observable sequence or Promise produces a value.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/takeuntil.md

> `timer` Returns an observable sequence that produces a value after dueTime has elapsed and then after each period.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/timer.md

You can simplify your logic here by handling the dispatch directly on each stream.

```
this.navigationEnd$ = router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError);

this.navigationStart$ = router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
  .subscribe(_ => {
    Observable.timer(160)
      .takeUntil(this.navigationEnd$)
      .subscribe(_ => this.store.dispatch({ type: StateLoaderSpinnerActionsTypes.SHOW_SPINNER });
  });

this.navigationEnd$.subscribe(_ => this.store.dispatch({ type: StateLoaderSpinnerActionsTypes.HIDE_SPINNER });
```

So what we've done is listen to the start of the navigation and start a `timer` for 160ms.  If the navigation end event happens before the timer, no spinner will show (`takeUntil`). Otherwise, the store action will be dispatched and the spinner will show.  Regardless of whether or not the spinner is showing, after the navigation finishes we dispatch the hide spinner action.

Comment: How does it help? Doesn't it cancel whole navigationStartStreamWithDelay stream after navigationStartStream emits?

Comment: @MykhailoI sorry I was trying to not change too much.  Please see the edits I made above and let me know if it is more clear.

Comment: thanks, it's clear.  
I'm just wondering is there a way not to dispatch HIDE_SPINNER if SHOW_SPINNER was not dispatched?
I want to refactor my load spinner, later, to make it generic, so I can use it for other network requests,  
I'm thinking on adding some counter in a store, and change showSpinner to false only if counter is zero,  
so additional HIDE_SPINNER dispatch, without previous SHOW_SPINNER,  would break that logic,  
and I would have to introduce some property in store to distinguish network load spinners and routing load spinners  
or some other workaround

Comment: @MykhailoI You could add a filter into the `navigationEnd$` stream which would check if the spinner is currently showing.

Answer (score 3):

My approach is based on Http requests, which may not work in every case since some apps will only use WebSockets or no external requests at all. But for a large set of apps, they are getting all their data via HttpClient (angular 4.3+). I wrote an HttpInterceptor that does just this.

```
import { HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Inject, Injectable, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs'
import { filter, takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'

const reqIsSpinnable = (req: HttpRequest<any>) => {
  return req.url.includes('api/')
}

@Injectable()
export class HttpSpinnerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: HTMLDocument, private rdf: 
    RendererFactory2) { }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-null-keyword
  readonly rdr = this.rdf.createRenderer(null, null)

  get spinnerElement() {
    return this.doc.querySelector('#core-spin')
  }

  startSpin() {
    this.rdr.setStyle(this.spinnerElement, 'display', 'block')
  }

  closeSpin() {
    this.rdr.setStyle(this.spinnerElement, 'display', 'none')
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<any> {
    const responseTimer$ = next.handle(req).pipe(filter(e => e instanceof HttpResponse))
    timer(120).pipe(takeUntil(responseTimer$)).subscribe(() => this.startSpin())

    return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(evt => {
      if (reqIsSpinnable(req) && evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.closeSpin()
      }
    }))
```

}
}